# SQL Server insert trigger with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I haven't ever tried using triggers before.

So this is the query I want to trigger when an insert is detected.

```
UPDATE USER_CHECK_LOGIN
   SET CHECKLOGIN = 2
 WHERE USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY IN
       (SELECT e.USER_KEY
          FROM XTREME.game.dbo.CHAR_DATA0 AS e
         INNER JOIN XTREME.gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 AS p
               ON e.CHAR_KEY = p.CHAR_KEY
         WHERE p.GATENUM = 150
       )
   AND USER_CHECK_LOGIN.CHECKLOGIN = 0
   AND USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY!=51;
```

But the problem is I've been searching around but can't find how using condition would work.

What I need is that script triggered when an insert is done on the table called `LOG_CONNECT201211` and if that insert contains the `gatenum=150` and `kind=21/22/23`

If kind is 21 then run this query, if 22 run this query if 23 run this query.

Something like that.

```
SELECT *
  FROM LOG_CONNECT201211
 WHERE GATENUM=150
   AND (KIND=21 OR KIND=22 OR KIND=23)
```

As you can see the tables end in `201211`, which means next month the table will be `201212`, so I also need the tables to automatically change to the current months table.

Comment: A trigger can run the SELECT that you give.  Did you want something done with the results?

Comment: The select is just an sample select for the table.

Comment: I can't help but notice your code uses four-part naming; are you referencing a linked server? Adding linked server code to a trigger is likely to cause performance problems. You might consider copying the target table to the local database by replication, or making this operation asynchonous and running it in a batch.

Answer (score 1):

Why need create table every month? It will be better add in table LOG_CONNECT column datetime. Hence it will be possible to check current month created once trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.triggerName ON LOG_CONNECT
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM inserted i
             WHERE GATENUM=150 AND KIND IN (21, 22, 23) AND DATEPART(mm, newColumnDate) = DATEPART(mm, GETDATE())
             )
  BEGIN
    ...your logic
  END 
END
```

Comment: Two comments: 1. A small typo as you are comparing the newColumnDate with itself (you may use INSERTED.newColumnDate instead or so) and 2. you should avoid using datepart for a comparison as it prevents the optimizer to use an index. When having data rows over time, it is usually a good idea to use a clustered index on the date/time column.

Comment: tnx @alzaimar. Very important recommendations.